# Refactor to avoid the setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to attach an event handler that will put a border around the item it is attached to when the item is hovered over. I would like to avoid the function setTimeout() if possible. Does anyone have any ideas? Kudos for directing me to a useful framework that could handle something like this.

The below code is the only way ive found how to do the below. The reason I need to do this is because I will be grabbing the html inside of the element and replacing it from db values. Here is my code:

```
    var color;
$(document).ready(function(){

    attachMouseEnter();
    // This is not resetting. How do I make it so I can reset this?
    function attachMouseEnter(){
        $('.editable').mouseenter(function(){
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).wrap('<span class="test"></span>')
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
        window.setTimeout(attachMouseOut(), 1000);
    }
    // this is making it so I cannot grab the element and attach a handler to it.
    function attachMouseOut(){
        $('.editable').mouseout(function(){
            var orginal = $(this);
            $(this).css("border", "0px");
            $(this).parent().replaceWith(orginal.parent().html());
            window.setTimeout(attachMouseEnter(), 1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `setTimeout` don't even work, because you invoke functions immediately (note how you place `()` after function names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call event handlers again and again. Just calling it once is enough..

```
var color;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('mouseenter','.editable',function(){
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).wrap('<span class="test"></span>')
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
    });
     $('body').on('mouseout','.editable',function(){
        var orginal = $(this);
        $(this).css("border", "0px");
        $(this).parent().replaceWith(orginal.parent().html());
    });
});
```